# How can we read default cell format from Excel in Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
public java.text.Format getDefaultFormat(Cell cell).
```

I am reading values from an Excel cell and storing it in a database.

The code below is not working, it's giving a type mismatch error.

```
userdata.setTaskid((int)(row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue()));
System.out.println(userdata.getTaskid());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question. When showing code, you can put it in `code markdown` by indenting it by 4 spaces. When adding tags to your question, please make sure they are relevant to the question. "Excel" is relevant to this question, so I added it; Spring is not, so I removed it. (You can roll my edit back if you disagree with it, BTW). The "apache" tag is only for the Apache web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will give you the cell format and then based on that return integer format you can decide the way to get cell value, e.g. either using getNumericCelValue or getBooleanCelValue etc.

```
int cellType = row.getCell(0).getCellType();
```

- Blank Value = 3
- Boolean Value = 4
- Error Value = 5
- Formula Value = 2
- Numeric Value = 0
- String value = 1

Comment: I used the above logic earlier and I am getting this error: Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell

Comment: Hence I want to read excel cell in default formats, if you read this link: http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html

Comment: There isn't any method in that api to get the return value in default/generic type, say Object type. Even if you look into the API code they use this getCellType() method and then based on return integer(e.g. Boolean Value = 4) value, uses switch cases to go to specific method type, like getIntegerValue or boolean. I recommend use above method and then using switch case, based on return type, use that getxxxxCellValue() method. This is what API people doing inside, in many of its methods.

Comment: Thankx brother.. Ya It is working fine now. All credit goes to you.. I added switch case and it worked.

Comment: Okay. You can accept the answer if this answers your question.